# Disabling sslv3 on samba4

Tags: ssl, ldap, samba4

How can I disable `sslv3` on `samba4 ldaps` and just have `tlsv1` enabled?

I have not been able to  find any documentation or guides on disabling this feature. This is in regards to the `poodle vulnerability`.

Comment: I haven't seen samba4 used as an ldap server.  It will connect to the samba4 using the protocols available from the ldap server.  Disabling sslv3 on the ldap server will disable its use by samba and other ldap clients.

Comment: The ldap server is included in samba4,act as Active directory server

Comment: Looking through my documentation it appears that Samba uses an LDAP server such as OpenLDAP to provide the LDAP services.  Try running `sudo netstat -antp | grep :636 to see which program is listening for LDAP traffic.

Comment: I dug deeper and it appears SAMBA has its own LDAP/Kerberos services. However, I don't see any options to configure tls ciphers or other options that can be used to disable sslv3.